# Multiplication of two intervals

Tags: math, python-3.x, intervals

As per the below question picked from self training [exercise](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/hw/hw3.html):

> In passing, Ben also cryptically comments, "By testing the signs of the endpoints of the intervals, it is possible to break mul_interval into nine cases, only one of which requires more than two multiplications." Write a fast multiplication function using Ben's suggestion:

```
def mul_interval_fast(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the product of any value in x and any
    value in y, using as few multiplications as possible.

    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-8 to 16'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-2, -1), interval(4, 8)))
    '-16 to -4'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 3), interval(-4, 8)))
    '-12 to 24'
    >>> str_interval(mul_interval_fast(interval(-1, 2), interval(-8, 4)))
    '-16 to 8'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

I could analyse that, below is the pattern of results:

```
(1, 3)(5, 7)  ---> [min(5, 7, 15, 21), max(5, 7, 15, 21)]              --->   (5, 21)
(-1, -3)(-5, -7)  --->  [min(5, 7, 15, 21), max(5, 7, 15, 21)]         --->   (5, 21)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(1, 3)(5, -7)  --->  [min(5, -7, 15, -21), max(5, -7, 15, -21)]        --->   (-21, 15)
(-1, 3)(5, -7)  --->  [min(-5, 7, 15, -21), max(-5, 7, 15, -21)]       --->   (-21, 15)
(1, -3)(-5, 7)  --->  [min(-5, 7, 15, -21), max(-5, 7, 15, -21)]       --->   (-21, 15)
(-1, -3)(-5, 7)  --->  [min(5, -7, 15, -21), max(5, -7, 15, -21)]      --->   (-21, 15)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(1, 3)(-5, 7)  --->  [min(-5, 7, -15, 21), max(-5, 7, -15, 21)]        --->   (-15, 21)
(-1, 3)(-5, 7)  --->  [min(5, -7, -15, 21), max(5, -7, -15, 21)]       --->   (-15, 21)
(1, -3)(5, -7)  --->  [min(5, -7, -15, 21), max(5, -7, -15, 21)]       --->   (-15, 21)
(-1, -3)(5, -7)  --->  [min(-5, 7, -15, 21), max(-5, 7, -15, 21)]      --->   (-15, 21)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(1, 3)(-5, -7)   ---> [min(-5, -7, -15, -21), max(-5, -7, -15, -21)]   --->   (-21, -5)
(-1, -3)(5, 7)  --->  [min(-5, -7, -15, -21), max(-5, -7, -15, -21)]   --->   (-21, -5)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(-1, 3)(5, 7)   ---> [min(-5, -7, 15, 21), max(-5, -7, 15, 21)]        --->   (-7, 21)
(1, -3)(-5, -7)  --->  [min(-5, -7, 15, 21), max(-5, -7, 15, 21)]      --->   (-7, 21)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
(-1, 3)(-5, -7) --->   [min(5, 7, -15, -21), max(5, 7, -15, -21)]      --->   (-21, 7)
(1, -3)(5, 7)  --->  [min(5, 7, -15, -21), max(5, 7, -15, -21)]        --->   (-21, 7)
```

But above pattern does not show those `nine cases`.

So, In specific, I would like to understand this point: `By testing the signs of the endpoints of the intervals, it is possible to break mul_interval into nine cases,`

Please help me on this interval arithmetic!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a homework service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand, but there are 3 cases for an interval `(a1,b1)`: `a<b<=0`, `a<0<b`, and `0<=a<b`. So for two intervals `(a1,b1)` and `(a2,b2)`, there are 3x3 = 9 cases. The most problematic as far as multiplication goes would be the case where `a1<0<b1` and `a2<0<b2`. Then you need to know the `min` and `max` of `a1*a2`, `b1*b2`, `a1*b2`, and `a2*b1` whereas the other cases are just scaling for which you need to know the two endpoints.

Comment: Your arrows go the wrong way. Furthermore, (-16,8) and (-8,16) are the same type of outcome. There should be only 3 types of outcomes, but 9 ways of getting there. Also, note that (a1,b1) x (a2,b2) where a1<0<b1 and a2<0<b2 could result in different outcomes depending on the relative values of a1, a2, b1, and b2.

Comment: 1) relatives values? question says, `By testing the signs of the endpoints of the intervals`.  2) I changed the arrow sign now.

Comment: What you have is better. Now delete some cases. For example, anything with (1,-3) is impossible because (1,-3) is not an interval.

Comment: Replace cases with (-1,-3) by (-3,-1).

Comment: I removed 'maybe even', since it's clear that you need `a2*b1` for e.g. `[0,1] * [-1,0] = [-1,0]`.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn It has been a while, so I can’t recall exactly what is was thinking, but IIRC there may be an option to switch the order of multiplication to avoid one of a2*b1 or a1*b2.

Answer (score 0):

You can check those cases:
Investigate whether or not the intervals overlap zero, or are always positive or negative you can break the problem down into cases where a maximum of two multiplies are needed.

Note the original question assumes that x[0] < x[1] and y[0] < y[1]

For example:

```
if (x[1] <= 0) {
   if (y[1] <= 0) {} // both negative
   if (y[0] >= 0) {} // one negative ane positive
   else {} // y is both negative and positive, x is only negative
}

if (x[0] >= 0) {
   if (y[1] <= 0) {} // one negative ane positive
   if (y[0] >= 0) {} // both positive
   else {} // y is both negative and positive, x is only positive
}
else {} //both overlap zero
```